# macOS not reading SDHC cards either with internal slot or external reader

Tags: macos, finder, mac-mini, sd-card

2012 Mac Mini, still running High Sierra (10.13.6)

Has suddenly stopped reading SDHC cards (even showing the card is available). Things I've tried:

- relaunch Finder (via right click) - occasionally required previously, and has always worked
- wiping the card contacts
- rebooting macOS
- disconnecting the Mac Mini and cleaning the rear SHDC slot (with slim bit of plastic)
- verifying the card works elsewhere (Macbook Air)
- testing with a brand new card
- connecting an 8-in-1 card reader via USB and putting the card in that
- checked Finder's display external disks setting was set correctly

Nothing obvious in Console log.
Disk Utility shows nothing. No card in /Volumes on terminal.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** ~ 24 hours later it has started working again. (At this stage I think I still suspect something physical to do with the slot, as I was getting intermittent results with the external reader today until I tried a second one...)  I'll add I've found ejecting cards can often take ages, but not consistently (and even when the contents are not being browsed in Finder).

Comment: Are the cards formatted? If so, how? i.e. FAT32, ext4, NTFS etc

Comment: @Seamus I mostly use FAT32 (because of the format the camera uses), but I just reformatted the new one as macOS Journaled on the Macbook Air and it still isn't recognised by the Mini.